# Where does the chlorine taste in yogurt come from?

Tags: flavor, milk, yogurt, tasting, frozen-yogurt

My parents used to make yogurt some years ago. When they tried to make some last month, it turned out very firm and smooth in appearence, but tasted like chlorine.

The taste is so strong that even strawberries couldn't get rid of it. Since then we have not tried making yogurt anymore.

Is the chlorine taste related to some fermentation level/age? Quality of milk?

Obs.: Though the chlorine taste was very strong, it wasn't sour.

Comment: When home brewing beer, chlorine or iodine can contribute to chlorphenol or iodophenol in the end product which have a chlorine-like or medicinal tastes.  I'm not 100% sure that it could happen in homemade yoghurt, but it might be a possibility.  Chlorine is often found in treated tap water and both chlorine and iodine is used as disinfectants in many dairies.  (http://chipre.iqm.unicamp.br/~marcia/Pub139.pdf)

Comment: I wanted drinking yoghurt so I "diluted" it with good known to me organic raw milk. no water EVER touched the equally good, active and organic yogurt that I added the milk to and I landed here because there was also a VERY strong chlorine taste to the end/somewhat fermented again drink.. so I doubt it has anything to do with the water...

Comment: Could you. Uh. 7 years later describe how the yogurt was made? How much milk, raw or pasteurized, how much yogurt starter, incubation time and temp...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Strangely enough, I do live near Campinas (where UNICAMP belongs), where water once was [contaminated by human hormones](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/cotidiano/ult95u129198.shtml)! (Note the source is not in English.) I'm noticing the local water smells very strongly of chlorine; I wonder they're adding water to milk before selling it, or if the cows are drinking the water...

I will try buying milk from different towns to test my theory.

Comment: Chlorine from chlorinated water drunk by cows would not end up in their milk.

Comment: I don't understand what the water being "contaminated with human hormones" has to do with the chlorine smell.